# How to update an array in a class which is changed by some other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've run into a problem which is, when I create a thread( of some other class) in a class, it takes an array of that class as a parameter for its constructor and changes it later in its run() function. How can I update the array in the class that creates the thread (i.e. to update the changes made by the thread)?

```
// public serverInit()
public connection[] myservers;
public void Threads()
{
  Thread accept=new Acception(myservers);
  accept.start();
}

// public class Acception extends Thread


public void run()
{
  try
  {
     while(true)
       {
        client = server.accept();
        if(client.isConnected())
        {
             for(int i=0;i<totalServers;i++)
            {

              String[] info=client.getInetAddress().toString().split(":");
                if(info[0].compareToIgnoreCase(myservers[i].getIp())==0)    
                {
                    myservers[i].setStatus("Active");
                    System.out.println("Request Received From server : " + 
                     client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                    Thread work=new server(client);
                    work.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
         }
        }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println("Connection with 
              "+client.getInetAddress().toString()+" failed :-(");
        }
     }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to update the array contents or the instance variables of the objects in the array?

Comment: The variables of the objects in the array.

Comment: Where is the other class that is changing things? Please see about a [mcve]

Comment: The class mentioned first 'serverInit' has an array **myservers**  which is passed as an argument when Thread **accept** is created. 
The second class mentioned 'Acception' is the one whose thread is created in **serverInit** and it changes the value of the variables of object within that array(myservers).

Comment: My question is how do I update **myservers** in serverInit after the values are changed by **accept** ( the thread)?

Comment: Actually you should not update array as there is no api for it, instead you shoud use ConcurrentHashMap which by default provides auto update facility provided in java.util.concurrent